# Visual Studio, the folder is not being generated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have defined a Win32 Application in Visual Studio and named my project as "Test". The structure that has been created and shown in Solution Explorer, is as follows:

```
- Test
- - References
- - External Dependencies
- - Header Files 
- - - stdafx.h
- - - targetver.h
- - Resource Files
- - Source Files 
- - - stdafx.cpp 
- - - myMainMethodHere.cpp 
- - ReadMe.txt
```

It also created a project in the file system at the following path: 
    C:{ path }\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Test\Test

The thing is, in IDE, when I create a new folder or upload existing file (I do it from IDE by right clicking - Add - Existing Item for existing files and Add - New Filter for a folder), whether I create it under Test dir directly or under Source Files, the folder/files uploaded are not shown in Windows Explorer (in the file system). The only files that pop up in the file system are those created as new items, but if I am adding existing ones, they won't reveal in my project's dir. Due to this, when I upload existing files, I get 'no source found' error in the references (include), and even if I specify the directories included (by right clickcing a project - properties - VC++ directories - include directories), the error is still present as no files being physically added to my project's dir.

How to fix it?

Comment: New Filter doesn't add a folder, it only organizes files internally. You have to create a new folder in the directory that you want.

Comment: You are pretty confused about the way a project works.  "Source Files" is *not* a directory, it is but a label to categorize files in your project.  And a project doesn't know anything about files you copied into the directory, only the ones you added to the project are displayed.  Consider using Project > Add Existing Item.  You'll save yourself a lot of time and grief by following a basic tutorial or introductory book.

Comment: Solution Explorer window toolbar has "Show all files" button that will switch display mode to actual filesystem content and allows creation of real folders etc.